# Using Font Awesome with Aurelia and npm... module not found

Tags: javascript, npm-install, aurelia

I am following the Aurelia Contact Manager tutorial and it says to use the following npm command to install font awesome.

npm install font-awesome

Then to add the following to the main.js file to import fa into the app.

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

However when running the app it cannot fine the module. When i look in the node-modules/font-awesome folder in the app src folder i noticed that it is missing the css folder. It looks like several files & folders are missing, unlike the bootstrap folder which has the files & folders referenced.

Any suggeations?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. Found the answer. Need to use --save on the npm install command, eg:

npm install font-awesome --save